# Automatically loading new messages onto page

Tags: php, ajax

I have a message table that has a few columns such as `id`, `to_id`, `from_id`, `is_read`, etc. I'm looking for the most reliable way to check if there are any new emails and if there are, load them in with jquery and display them to the logged in user. I was thinking about using the `is_read` column and if its not read then pull it in but sometimes the user just wont open the message so I don't want to pull it in again. What is the best way to check for new messages? I just want new messages to load into the inbox if the user is sitting on the inbox page.

Comment: its' not a good idea to keep poking at something regardless. read about long polling

Comment: Are you just looking for the code to check every 5 seconds or do you need the display code and other stuff as well?

Comment: Sorry, I understand how to check every 5 seconds. I'm just wondering the best way to go about looking for new messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your API should accept either a `last_message_id` or a `last_checked_at` parameter, and only return messages which are newer than that id/timestamp. Client side, you should ask for messages which are newer than your newest message, or the messages at the "top" of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically calling out is not a good idea. It creates a lot of overhead you don't need.

If you have your heart set on it,

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){ <code here> }, 50);
</script>
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Otherwise, look at [Pusher](http://pusher.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to do that. I'm just wondering the best way to go about looking for new messages and don't pull messages that are already loaded into the inbox.

Comment: Oh sure thing. On page load, save the output of time() to session/cookie, and then in your setInterval, use [jQuery $.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to get data from a PHP file. In this PHP file (and consequently in your SQL statement), check for messages which were sent after that timestamp.